# Missing C# Rules in SonarQubeversion 6.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

Earlier I was using `SONARQUBE 5.5` and `sonar-csharp-plugin-5.0` which was having `407 C# Rules`. But now i have upgraded to `SonarQube 6.4` with which `sonar-csharp-plugin-5.10.1.1411` comes by default and it has only `229 rules`. I tried using the older version of `SonarC#` plugin but it is not compatible with this `SonarQube version`. Is there any way I can get all the `C# Rules` in `SonarQube 6.4`

Answer (score 1):

The "407 rules" number included all of the Roslyn-based analysis rules written by SonarSource and the approximately 230 rules implemented in the now-obsolete FxCop.

Support for the FxCop rules was split out into a separate plugin, so from version 5.4 onwards the SonarC# plugin only contains the Roslyn-based analysis rules implemented by SonarSource.

If you still want to use the legacy FxCop rules you can install the [community plugin](https://github.com/DanielHWe/sonar-fxcop).

However, we have been re-implementing the most useful FxCop rules in the SonarC# plugin using Roslyn. The latest version (v7.1) of the SonarC# plugin now has [343 rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp) with more being added in each release.